# Jenkins email notification is success but emails are not received

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Following is the success logs I see on Jenkins console logs but the emails are not received, I've correctly updated SMTP in `Email notification` and  `Extended E-Mail Notification` sections

```
Email was triggered for: Always
Sending email for trigger: Always
Sending email to: arunxp@XXX.com
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Please let me know do I need to do any other settings

Comment: Did you check spam folder? also your jenkins installed on any server or on local?

Comment: Yeah, I checked in spam folder as well, and not emails are received. Jenkins installed on local

Comment: How can this be related to `Selenium` tag? Am I missing something?

Comment: @DebanjanB  - Agree with you. I removed selenium tag.

Comment: @arunkumarsambu - Can you try to put any gmail address as TO and then check? I feel there is some issue with your server email. if it works fine with gmail then you must check with your email config.

Comment: It should definitely the wrong in the configuration. Did you put authentication, smtp server and port values correctly?? Please check once. Try to send out a sample email using these configured creds via a script.

Comment: Usually the SMTP settings in Jenkins will have a test email functionality. Try that too.